# How to insert text at caret for ipywidgets textarea

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, ipywidgets

I am using ipywidgets in a jupyter notebook and am trying to insert text into a Text box. I have code that will append the appropriate text to the end, but I would like it to insert at the current text cursor instead. Here is a mock up of what a currently have:

```
from ipywidgets import Button,Text

a = Text(description='text',
         disabled=False)
b = Button(description='Awesome',
       disabled=False)

def on_button_clicked(b):
    a.value+=b.description

b.on_click(on_button_clicked)

display(a,b)
```

When I tried to google my question, I found lots of examples for doing this with javascript or tk, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this with ipywidgets.

How do I get the caret position of the ipywidgets Text box?

Comment: I don't think there is an inbuilt method to do this in ipywidgets, the JS methods you discovered elsewhere might be your best bet

Comment: I was afraid there wasn't a way to do this directly with ipywidgets. I'm not really sure how to implement the JS methods in a python notebook, but that seems like the next thing to start googling.